# Como retornar a quantidade total quando se usa OFFSET e FETCH NEXT?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, sqlfiddle

Precisei usar `OFFSET` e `FETCH NEXT` para retornar um range de dados entre minha consulta.

## Tabela

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Usuario]
(
  [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [Email] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
  [Nome] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
  [SobreNome] [nvarchar](max) NULL
);
    
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Usuario]([Email],[Nome],[SobreNome])
VALUES
(1,'marconi@gmail.com','Marconi Barroso'),
(2,'magnoAlef@gmail.com','Magno Barroso');
```

## Select:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) Total, * from Usuario
GROUP BY Id, Email, Nome, SobreNome
ORDER BY Id
OFFSET 1 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 2 ROWS ONLY
```

Porém necessito saber qual a quantidade total de registro pelo fato de que estou paginando os resultados em uma tabela.

Vejam que esse resultado me retorna apenas 1 registro quando na verdade tenho 2, como poderia adicionar um `COUNT` que me retornaria todos os registros?

## [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d19e3/3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ficam aqui duas alternativas. A primeira fazendo recurso à função COUNT, enquanto função de janela.

```
SELECT COUNT(1) OVER() AS total, 
       T1.* 
  FROM Usuario T1
 ORDER BY Id
OFFSET 1 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 2 ROWS ONLY
;
```

O [OVER()](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-BR/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) é usado normalmente para definir a "janela" (ou intervalo de linhas/registos) sobre o conjunto completo de resultados da query, sobre o qual a função de janela (aqui o COUNT) será aplicada.

Neste caso, como não foi especificada nenhuma partição e não foi aplicado qualquer filtro sobre a tabela Usuario, a função COUNT será aplicada ao conjunto completo de resultados, i.e., irá devolver o número total de registos existentes na tabela Usuario.

A segunda alternativa, mais convencional, faz o cálculo do total separado.

```
SELECT  X.Total,
        T1.ID, 
        T1.Email, 
        T1.Nome, 
        T1.SobreNome
FROM Usuario T1 
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT COUNT(1) AS Total From Usuario ) X
ORDER BY T1.ID
OFFSET 1 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 2 ROWS ONLY
;
```

> Apesar de o resultado ser o mesmo neste caso particular, eu alterei
>   aqui para CROSS JOIN ao invés do CROSS APPLY. penso não se justificar
>   neste caso em particular, pois o CROSS APPLY é usado normalmente
>   quando queremos estabelecer uma dependência entre as duas tabelas, ou
>   por exemplo, aplicar uma função a cada linha de resultados. Ficou na
>   resposta final apenas porque estava brincar com o fiddle e a comparar
>   os resultados das duas versões. Me desculpe, pelo mesmo.

Voltando à resposta, esta segunda forma talvez mais intuitiva, efectua um produto cartesiano entre os conjuntos de resultados de T1 (Usuarios) e X, i.e., devolve o resultado de combinar cada uma das linhas da tabela T1 com as linhas da tabela X. Como neste caso X tem apenas 1 registo, o resultado final consiste nas linhas da tabela Usuario com uma coluna adicional que corresponde ao total de registos.

Esta segunda alternativa, dependendo do tamanho da tabela, pode ser mais rápida. Mas eu gosto mais da primeira :)

Fica aqui o [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e6bcc/12)

Comment: Sem problema @Marconi :)
Tentei explicar um pouco a lógica de cada um dos casos. Por favor diga se não ficou claro o suficiente.

Comment: Ficou bom demais @bruno :)